# Center two images with different heights/widths vertically aligned by the center with captions at the bottom

Tags: floatrow

I want to center two images side by side, that are vertically aligned by the center with the captions at the bottom. I managed to do everything, except to center them.
Here is the picture:

[image: example]

Here is my code:

```
\usepackage{caption,floatrow}
\DeclareCaptionSubType[alph]{figure}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=colon}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=brace,labelsep=space,labelfont=bf}
\floatsetup[subfigure]{capposition=bottom,heightadjust=object,valign=c}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\ffigbox[\hsize]
{\begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox
        {\includegraphics[height=.6\hsize]{radar.png}}
        {\caption{Feature radar}\label{fig:radar}}
    \ffigbox
        {\includegraphics[height=1.2\hsize]{map.png}}
        {\caption{Map}\label{fig:map}}
    \end{subfloatrow}}
    {\caption{Set plot}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And before that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx,url}
\graphicspath{ {./Figures/} }
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{xspace} % for new command space
\usepackage{hyperref} % alternatively use url
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox | align figures
\usepackage{caption,floatrow}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What do you mean? Horizontally centred?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I want the left margin of the first image to be equal to the right margin of the second one.

Comment: That's what I obtain with this code (adding `\centering, just after `\begin{figure}`).

Comment: This doesn't change anything for me..

Comment: I know, but it means there's something else in your real code which is responsible for your difficulty Compiling this this code isn't centred for you?

Comment: Oh, I see. I updated the question with what I have before

Comment: I'm sorry,  but even with your preamble (and the `demo` option for `graphics`), it remains disappointingly centred for me. What happens if you compile this sole code?

Comment: Even compiling just this part, it still doesn't change

Comment: Did you try adding `\centering`?

Comment: I did, but it didn't change the result. I tried scaling down the images too, but it didn't work either.

Comment: A last idea: can you check the bounding boxes of the images? Or try compilng with standar images from package `mwe`.

Comment: I'll try to do that, thanks

Comment: The bounding boxes are correctly centred, but the images are not. Maybe what I need is to scale the bounding boxes widths

Comment: You might nest your `\includegraphics{…}` in an `\fbox` to have something more visual, and experiment for possible solutions more easily.

Comment: I managed to correct it, but I don't know the reason for why the scales I used worked.. I'll post it here

Comment: As an alternative to floatrow, you could use a tabular to align the images and subcaptions in separate rows, but you would need p columns or parboxes for the captions, which means you would need widths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach, achieved by

- adjusting the vertical alignment of first (also shorter) figure to its center (with the option `align=c` from `graphbox` package), and
- inserting a vertically centered zero-width box with height of second (also taller) figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphbox} % it depends on "graphicx" package
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{A cat\label{cat}}
  {%
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,align=c]{example-image}%
    \vphantom{\includegraphics[width=6cm,align=c]{example-image}}%
  }\qquad
\subcaptionbox{An elephant\label{elephant}}
  {\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image}}
\caption{Two animals}\label{animals}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I managed to make it work:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \ffigbox[\hsize]
        {\begin{subfloatrow}
            \ffigbox[.5\hsize]
                {\includegraphics[width=\FBwidth]{radar.png}}
                {\caption{Feature radar}\label{fig:radar}}
            \ffigbox[1.4\hsize]
                {\includegraphics[width=\FBwidth]{map.png}}
                {\caption{Map}\label{fig:map}}
        \end{subfloatrow}}
    {\caption{Set plot}}
\end{figure}
```

And the result with the bounding boxes around the images
[image: working example]